# IntellIj Idea 2016.2 where to find him to uninstall

Tags: 16.04, intellij

I've installed IntellIj Idea v2016.2.5, but now after upgrade i'm install a new version to. Question is,how to **uninstall** old version,if i don't remember where is installed.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.IntelliJIdea <VERSION>`  Choose version to uninstall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To uninstall it you have to look in your home directory. So open your terminal and:

```
cd ~
ls -a
```

There you should see directories called `.intellij...` folowed by the version number. To remove them simply do:

```
rm -r <direcory-name>
```

There should be, if JetBrains follows their own rules two of those directories called so, one for the program and one for settings.

For more comprehensive  location information check out [their documentation page about that](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519).

Comment: Did as you said but still the shortcut is their in the unity dash board, how to remove it

Comment: I did this to remove the zombie icon
`rm ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`